# Error when publishing Workflow from SharePoint Designer 2013 to SharePoint Online

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to publish a very simple workflow from SharePoint Designer 2013 to **SharePoint Online**.
The following error appears:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPrincipalManagementException: An error occurred
>   while attempting to execute a principal management operation.  Please
>   contact your administrator. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.WebService.PropertyValidationException]:
>   Invalid property specified
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Cal

How can I handle this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is your workflow able to run on your local SP Designer? if yes, you probobly want to check if you account is correctly linked to SPO and have enough permission to do it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the account or WF it self. This issue only happens when I deploy WFs to SPO in Developer subscription. The deployment goes smoothly on Enterprise subscription. That is quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a new sub-site from your site collect then upload your workflow to see if its viable.

If not, you can check whether the Central Admin > Manage Service Application-> “App Management Service” is started.

Also heck whether the “Configure service application associations”,  ”App Management Service” is already associated.

Then check whether the “Manage Services on server” and the “App Management Service” is started.

In addition, try to re-register Workflow Service.

If the issues still exists, please follow the steps in the [Steps to Verify that Server Is Correctly Set Up.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/workflow-manager/jj193529(v=azure.10)#ServerSetup) After you verified that the server is correctly set up, follow the steps in the [Steps to Troubleshoot Workflow Management Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/workflow-manager/jj193529(v=azure.10)#WorkflowManagementService) and [Troubleshooting the Service Bus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj193001(v=azure.10).aspx) for Windows Server then retry your action.

If all above doesn't solve problem, then you should create a service request to Microsoft in SharePoint Online Admin Portal directly. Since issue is more likely related to SharePoint Online Server Back end.

[image]

Comment: I believe that SharePoint On-premise has "Manage Service Application" section in Central Admin; however, I cannot see that in SharePoint admin center of Office 365.

Comment: @victor_luu i would suggest you to contact [support](https://support.office.com/en-us/sharepoint) for help. Since this issue is most likely the server side issue and SPO is hosted from Microsoft, i don't think there is much you can do from your end.